# Need to identify which textbox is used using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, client-side-validation

I have four text boxes in 4 different tabs of an ASP.NET Page. I need to provide same validation message to all the text boxes. Presently I am using four different functions with same functionality. Kindly suggest a way to identify which textbox is being used make that a single funtion

Code from Commend:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="textBox1" runat="server" ValidationonGroup="abcd"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:CustomValidator ID="ID1" runat="server" ValidationGroup="abcd"
ControlToValidate="textBox1" ErrorMessage="message"
ClientValidationFunction="fname"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

--Javascript Fn--

```
function fname(sender, args) { 
 var x = document.getElementById('<%=txtBox1.ClientID%>').value;
 if (some condition) { 
  args.IsValid = false; 
 } else { 
  args.IsValid = true; 
 } 
}
```

Comment: can you add the code that you tried

Comment: I added only separate codes for 4 textboxes. I need to identify which textbox is used when click the save button

Comment: Well. You can pass your textbox reference in click event to identify which textbox it is. Something like, while calling onclick=`CallMe(this)`; And within function you will have function CallMe(obj). Here you can access obj var as your textbox.

Comment: My code is below. I have four textboxes and four functions presently. I have to make it one finction

<asp:TextBox ID="textBox1"  runat="server" ValidationonGroup="abcd"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:CustomValidator ID="ID1" runat="server" ValidationGroup="abcd" ControlToValidate="textBox1"  ErrorMessage="message" ClientValidationFunction="fname"></asp:CustomValidator>




--Javascript Fn--
function fname(sender, args) {
var x = document.getElementById('<%=txtBox1.ClientID%>').value;
            if (some condition) {
                args.IsValid = false;
            } else {
args.IsValid = true;
} 
}

Comment: see the above code along with question

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

if you are using Asp.Net then you should use like this

**Aspx page code**

```
<div>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt1" ClientIDMode="Static" onKeyPress="javascript:text_changed(this.id);"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
```

**JS Code**

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        function text_changed(event)
        {
            var id = event;
            alert(id);
        }
    </script>
```

You got the textbox id in id variable and now u can get value etc using this id you are applying your conditions.... i hope this will help u

Comment: My code is below. I have four textboxes and four functions presently. I have to make it one finction

<asp:TextBox ID="textBox1"  runat="server" ValidationonGroup="abcd"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:CustomValidator ID="ID1" runat="server" ValidationGroup="abcd" ControlToValidate="textBox1"  ErrorMessage="message" ClientValidationFunction="fname"></asp:CustomValidator>
       --Javascript Fn--
function fname(sender, args) {
var x = document.getElementById('<%=txtBox1.ClientID%>').value;
            if (some condition) {
                args.IsValid = false;
            } else {
args.IsValid = true;
} 
}